# Adding data with Heredoc

Tags: php, mysql, heredoc

normally this list is very long but i cut some fields because i want to show you what i want exactly. But structure is like this. I need to put some variables to this Heredoc but when we go deeper i am going to failure.

I am using this for send data from my website to crm.
I have products in my table. Please check the table;

tblitemable table

| id | rel_id | rel_type | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 9 | invoice | product1 |
| 12 | 10 | invoice | product2 |
| 13 | 11 | invoice | product3 |
| 14 | 9 | invoice | product4 |

and tblitems table

| id | sk_key | main_key | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 99 | 0000001 | product1 |
| 36 | 89 | 0002331 | product2 |
| 37 | 76 | 0000043 | product3 |
| 48 | 65 | 0000123 | product4 |

When i put $sk_key and $main_key variables below codes, crm adding each row as different order. But as you can see (rel_id) i have two piece "9" id and two piece other ids. That means one order will have 2 row for products. Normally ti have to add 3 order but its adds 4 order.

```
foreach ($rows as $ordert) {

    $customer = $ordert['c_code'];
    $sk_key = $ordert['sk_key'];
    $main_key = $ordert['main_key'];

        $data = <<<EOT
        {"add_order" :
            {"session_id": "$session_id",
             "order":
                    {
                    "customer_code": {"c_code": "$customer"},
                    "warehouse": {"warehousecode": "FB001"},
                    "order_rows": [{ 
                                  "sk_key": "$sk_key",
                                  "main_key": "$main_key",
                                       "m_variants": [{
                                            "variant1": 0,
                                            "variant2": 0,}]},
                                  "order_kind_service": "$order_kind_service",
                                  "order_unit_service": "$order_unit_service",}],
                    "shipping": "$shipping",
                    "billing": "$billing",
                  }
            }
      }
                 EOT;
```

}

and my select code is; (i am adding data from other tables too but important part is above)

```
$sendorder = $mysqli->query
('SELECT * FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues a 
INNER JOIN tblinvoices b ON a.relid = b.id
INNER JOIN tblclients c ON b.clientid = c.userid
INNER JOIN tblitemable d ON b.id = d.rel_id
INNER JOIN tblitems e ON e.description = d.description
WHERE a.value = "Yes"');
$rows = $senderoder->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

So, all values going to crm successfully but $sk_key and $main_key give me trouble.
I think i have to make some loops for this values.

If i am missing something please tell me. I have deleted a lot of codes from this file for explain myself clearly. I might make mistake here but i hope you understand what i want to do.

Thank you!

Comment: You appear to be trying to generate JSON by hand. Don't. Instead, build a PHP object / array structure and then use json_encode to create a JSON string from it - that's what it's there for. It'll be easier to code, and a lot less error-prone.

Comment: FYI `EOT` is just a symbol. What you're using is called [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)